# Including external JS file in xhtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

I'm trying to include jquery and few external js files in my index.php file.
I tried this at first:

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="file1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="file2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="file3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but it didn't work in IE9(compatibilty mode with IE7). So I tried this:

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="file1.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="file2.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="file3.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

which is wrong and doesn't work in any browser. But if I do this:

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="file1.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="file2.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="file3.js" type="text/javascript" /></script>
```

which seems to work but the last file is not included.
I can't supply you with the original code, sorry.

Can anyone tell me what is the correct way of doing this? Am I doing anything wrong?

*Ps:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pl" xml:lang="pl">
```

**EDIT:**

As T.J. Crowder said the html tags were ok, the problem is inside my script. I worked out where it is and the problem seems to be in these lines. This is the script I got from SO that checks whether browser supports `input[type=date]`. <s>If you could just tell me an easy way to check it in IE without breaking the whole script I would appreciate.</s> Never mind I changed `tester.type = "date";` to `tester.setAttribute("type", "date");` and it works in IE as well.

```
var tester = document.createElement('input');
tester.type = "date";
//if type date is not supported create own mask
if(tester.type !== "date")
```

Comment: *"but it didn't work in IE9(compatibilty mode with IE7)."* Define "didn't work." Your first set of examples is the correct way to do it.

Comment: None of the files were included. The Jquery wasn't working at all.

Comment: Not that it should matter, but where is it being included? In the head or body? Are you sure that there aren't any other parsing errors in the document causing issues? HTML is pretty forgiving, but unclosed tags or improper nesting can cause erratic behavior.

Comment: it has nothing to do with html xmlns in current case. Are you sure you have correct patches? Say, are you sure that `file1.js` does exists as well as another ones?

Comment: also add very first function to catch errors: `window.onerror = function(e){alert(e);}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is "What's the correct way to do this?" and the answer is "The way you did it in your first set of examples." :-)

You've said your first set of examples "didn't work" and in the comments explained further that...

> ...None of the files were included. The Jquery wasn't working at all.

It's not a problem with your `script` tags, your first set of examples is correct. Look in the F12 Dev Tools and you'll likely find that the scripts aren't where you think they are (e.g., you're getting 404s), or you're getting script errors (e.g., the files *were* included, but script errors prevented their working correctly).

Comment: He seems to imply that it was working in other browsers -- just not IE in compatibility mode. That wouldn't be a 404 issue.

Comment: @Apropos: Then it will be a script error or some such. The fundamental answer doesn't change. :-)

Comment: @t-j-crowder Fair point -- although corrupted DOM may not. Depends on the console, I guess. Not familiar with IE's.